# unwanted drop shadow on svg text

Tags: html, text, svg

There's a strange drop shadow on my SVG text. The reference guide i bought on Amazon doesn't have any answers. I cant seem to figure out how it got there, and how to remove it. There aren't any filters applied, and the markup matches examples of plain text.

heres the text element:
`<text class="noToggle" data-nodetitle="Node 1" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" x="510" y="420" textLength="230"  fill="#d90000">Node Title Goes Here</text>`

[image]

Comment: I should note that the data-nodetitle and class attributes do not affect the appearance when removed. I'm also using the jQuery mobile framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the white shadow, you can override the jquerymobile css and set it to none, example:

```
<p style="text-shadow: none">This text used to have a white shadow</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I traced the problem to jQuery mobile 1.1. It was inheriting a style rule from the body div where jQm was applying a 1px white text shadow. I wasn't aware that SVG text can be affected by this specific css style rule. Obviously in chrome and safari webkit browsers, it can.